# How do I extract part of the filename?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a file name 
415-11-CV-21654-CBB-20190228-0-transactions.csv. 
I want to have 11-CV-21654-CBB from the name above. How do I do that using a Regular expression in a sql query

Comment: Could you share what you have tried?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) we need to have a bit more example data.. is the format always `NNN-NN-DD-NNNNN-DDD` where N is a number a D is digit?

Comment: How fixed is the filename? Is the prefix always going to have the format `999-99-AA-99999-AAA-` ?.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
with t(str) as
(
  select '415-11-CV-21654-CBB-20190228-0-transactions.csv' from dual
)
select substr(str,1,instr(str,to_char(sysdate,'-yyyy')) - 1  )
   as "Result String"
  from t;

Result String
-------------------
415-11-CV-21654-CBB
```

or the other one :

```
with t(str,year) as
(
  select '415-11-CV-21654-CBB-20190228-0-transactions.csv', to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') 
    from dual
)
select rtrim(regexp_substr(str,'(*.)+'||year),'-'||year)
   as "Result String"
  from t

Result String
-------------------
415-11-CV-21654-CBB
```

to extract the part upto the current year with hyphen prefix.

Comment: This would work providing we know the filename will always have the current year in its name. The question is unclear on this point, but I think a solution which worked for any year would be better.

Comment: @APC I agree, but need to catch a distinguishing clue, and this seems the logically true. Otherwise, How can we know the presented number is a year ?

Comment: @hetulvaraiya you're welcome. Btw, could you explain the logic whether you need to extract upto current year or upto 5th hyhen, or what else ..? And please edit your question due to this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(fname, '^[^-]+-([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+).*$', '\1')
from (select '415-11-CV-21654-CBB-20190228-0-transactions.csv' as fname from dual) x
```

Comment: @hetulvaraiya - if you found this answer useful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow as a resource for other Seekers.